# send push notification to all iOS devices

Tags: python, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

Currently I am building an app where Firebase is the database.
I want to send a push notification to all iOS devices if the database gets a new entry.

I found already solutions with **topics** and **device_token**. Is there a way to do this without this? I don't have topics in my app and no device_token of all users.

I know that is possible with the Firebase Admin SDK. I would like to use Python.

Comment: You need the push notification tokens of the devices you want to send to.

Comment: And how I can get this tokens? Do I have to store them in Firebase Database?

Comment: Yes, your app will get the token in  your app delegate when it registers for remote notifications; you need to store this somewhere.

Comment: So basically if a user downloads my app his device token get saved into firebase database. And if I want to send push notification I need to get all of this device_tokens to send a message?

Comment: Yes.  That is correct.

Comment: Ok thank you. If I want to upload this app to the App Store can I get any trouble, because I am storing device_tokens of users?

Comment: No.  Storing device tokens is what you are expected to do.  How else could you send push notifications?

Comment: Don't know. Thats why I was asking. Thank you for you help :)